# Arduino LED On/Off TCP C#

Tags: c#, arduino, ethernet

I am now for Arduino, I want try to open switch on/off a led using C# with Arduino. So I try using serial port, and it works, but I want to use an Ethernet shield  to switch on/off the led.
My code using serial port
This Arduino code

```
    #define BaudRate 9600
#define LEDPin    10
char incomingOption;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);
  // serial communication
  Serial.begin(BaudRate);
}
void loop()
{
     //read from serial port getting information from VS 2013
     incomingOption = Serial.read();
     //verify incomingOption
     switch(incomingOption){
        case '1':
          // Turn ON LED
          digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
          break;
        case '0':
          // Turn OFF LED
          digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
          break;
     }
}
```

and for C#, I have 3 simple button (on, off, and close the serial port)

```
    public partial class frmTurnONTurnOFFLED : Form
{
   public frmTurnONTurnOFFLED()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
   private void btnTurnON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      try
      {
         serialPort1.Write("1"); //send 1 to Arduino
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
   }
   private void btnTurnOFF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      try
      {
         serialPort1.Write("0"); //send 0 to Arduino
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
   }
   private void frmTurnONTurnOFFLED_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      serialPort1.Open(); //open serialPort
   }
   private void btnClosePort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      serialPort1.Close(); //close serialPort
   }        
}
```

So where can I modify my code? using socket? using TCP pr UDP?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try set port name before open?

```
serialPort1.PortName = "COM3" // your ardunio port (you can see on device manager)
serialPort1.Open();
```

Comment: its just a test, I need to rewrite with Ethernet connection

Comment: @Juste3alfaz oh sorry, i m confused. Maybe this helps you link:https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/web-server-LED-control/

Comment: I see web page but I am using desktop application in C# but thnx :D